# Web download image and save to folder

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use the VBA-Web library (https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Web) to download an image and save it to my computer.

This code works fine but I want to check its the right way to get the job done. VBA isn't a my primary experience.

```
Sub Run()

    Dim client As New WebClient
    With client
        .BaseUrl = "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=160x160&chld=L|0&chl=hello"
        .EnableAutoProxy = True
    End With

    Dim request As New WebRequest
    With request
        .Method = WebMethod.HttpGet
        .AddHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
    End With

    Dim Response As WebResponse
    Set Response = client.Execute(request)

    ProcessResponse Response

End Sub

Sub ProcessResponse(Response As WebResponse)

    Dim oStream As Object

    Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    oStream.Open
    oStream.Type = 1
    oStream.Write Response.Body
    oStream.SaveToFile Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\image_test.png", 2
    oStream.Close

End Sub
```

I have used various other methods to download and had working including XMLHTTP and URLDownloadToFile but due to network issues I need the proxy handling that VBA-Web offers...

Comment: Hi, If it works but you are looking for a critique then consider the [code review site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). SO is for specific programming problems. On the face of it the code looks well and good.

Comment: Ah thank you. My apologies.

Answer (score 4):

no need to use custom libraries, try this

```
Public Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" Alias _
   "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long, _
   ByVal szURL As String, _
   ByVal szFileName As String, _
   ByVal dwReserved As Long, _
   ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long

Public Sub GURoL(url As String, FileName As String)
Dim lngRetVal As Long
    lngRetVal = URLDownloadToFile(0, url, FileName, 0, 0)
    If lngRetVal <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "GURol godo: Can't download from " & url & " to " & FileName
    End If
End Sub

Sub Download_Procedure()
Call GURoL("http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/ms348103.LOGO_WINDOWS(en-us,MSDN.10).png", _
           "c:\Temp\plik.png") '<change your dest. path
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. But as stated in the question this doesn't work for me due to internal networking issues.

Comment: The bottom line under the code "I have used various other methods to download and had working including XMLHTTP and URLDownloadToFile but due to network issues I need the proxy handling that VBA-Web offers..." the issue is we have an internal system that requires an automated login when accessing the outside web.

Comment: Thank you for the help though.

Answer (score 1):

Note: in case you got the error massage **"Compile error: The code in this project must be updated for use on 64-bit systems. Please review and update Declare statements and then mark them with the PtrSafe attribute".**
[Image of this prompted error massage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fqB5.png)
[image]

try add the `PtrSafe` keyword to `Declare` statement could help.

For example, make change of the above code snippet to be

```vb
Public Declare PtrSafe Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" Alias _
```

This is also working on Excel 2016 64-bit.

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/ptrsafe-keyword