# How to use VBA through Powerpoint to save a URL image to a folder?

Tags: vba, automation, powerpoint

I need to use Powerpoint or VBA to save a URL’s image to a folder on my windows computer. The purpose is that i’m trying to embed a pic of a Tableau dashboard to my powerpoint, but for some reason the pic won’t show up when I insert it. Using VBA should work as i can save the image to a folder with VBA, and then insert it into the powerpoint from the folder using VBA.

Right now, this is the code I'm using in EXCEL to try and save the image from Tableau to a windows folder. Either Excel VBA or Powerpoint VBA will work for this purpose:

```
    Public Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" Alias _
   "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long, _
   ByVal szURL As String, _
   ByVal szFileName As String, _
   ByVal dwReserved As Long, _
   ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long

Public Sub GURoL(url As String, FileName As String)
Dim lngRetVal As Long
    lngRetVal = URLDownloadToFile(0, url, FileName, 0, 0)
    If lngRetVal <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "GURol godo: Can't download from " & url & " to " & FileName
    End If
End Sub

Sub Download_Procedure()

'Saves an image to folder, needs to have jpg tho it looks like
'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51858575/web-download-image-and-save-to-folder/51859060#51859060

Call GURoL("https://us-west-1.online.tableau.com/TableauaddressExample.png", _
           "G:\My Drive\FolderExample.png") '<change your dest. path
End Sub
```

So I'm using the above code to save an image. However, it does not work with the tableau image, but it does work with other jpg images on google. Which is weird.

Once I fix that step, I can use the below to save the image from my folder with powerpoint VBA:

```
    Sub AddSavedImage()
  'Adds a picture from your folder
  'https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/use-vba-to-insert-a-picture-file-onto-a-powerpoint-slide/
  
  ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes.AddPicture( _
   FileName:="G:\FolderExample\FileExample.png", _
   LinkToFile:=msoFalse, _
   SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, Left:=60, Top:=35, _
   Width:=98, Height:=48).Select
End Sub
```

Can someone help me automate saving a tableau URL image? It would work if I could automatically insert the tableau URL image (which i have found), but that gives an error when I insert it into ppt as well.

Comment: Sorry, this isn't a code-writing service. Once you get some VBA written, we can help you debug it.

Comment: Hi @JohnKorchok, I've added my code. Could you please try to help me out?

Comment: I'd like to help, but https://us-west-1.online.tableau.com doesn't seem to be a real page, or at least not one I can open. Is it a site you have to sign in to? If, so, you have no code to do that, which may be why it's failing. I also don't know what the difference is between a tableau image and a standard PNG.

Answer (score 0):

This tableau website/URL image will need you to login to access it. You may be able to do this with VBA. But as the other commenter says, probably the domain is wrong